# Parent & grandparent div class checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, window.location

Is there a way to test if your current URL location matches with a link on your page, but also checking that the matching link's parent (or maybe grandparent) div has a particular div class?

e.g.
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

```
// find a-href on page with matching current location URL link
jQuery("*").find("a[href='"+window.location.href+"']").each(function(){

    // if matching a-href's parent contains class .aaa
    // then BBB action

    // else if matching a-href's grand-parent contains class .bbb
    // then CCC action

})});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) and [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass). Also note you don't need (or want) that initial `jQuery("*")`, and your code has an extra `})` at the end:

```
// find a-href on page with matching current location URL link
jQuery("a[href='"+window.location.href+"']").each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    // if matching a-href's parent contains class .aaa
    // then BBB action
    if (parent.hasClass("aaa")) {
        // ...
    }

    // else if matching a-href's grand-parent contains class .bbb
    // then CCC action
    else if (parent.parent().hasClass("bbb")) {
        // ...
    }
});
```